# Wait taking data from one widget to other one appear

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the user to pick a date using datePicker widget, when the user finish picking a date, a timePicker widget should appear and do the same thing. After that an item will be added to a list which uses the picked date & time. But what really happens is that everything shows up at the same time.

```
onPressed: () {
   var date = DateTime.now();
   showMaterialDatePicker(
      context: context,
      selectedDate: date,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => date = value),
   );
              
   //Should wait until DatePicker finish
   var time = TimeOfDay.now();
   showMaterialTimePicker(
      context: context,
      selectedTime: time,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => time = value),
   );
              
   //Should wait until timePicker finish, to add the item to the list
   this.widget.litems.add(Reminder(
      time: time,
      date: date,
   ));
   setState((){});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the showDatePicker & showTimePicker. As per the documentation [showDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) and [showTimePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showTimePicker.html) returns Future. You can simply await these for the desired outcome.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
   var date = DateTime.now();
   date = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: date,
   );
              
   //Should wait until DatePicker finish
   var time = TimeOfDay.now();
   time = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: time,
   );
              
   //Should wait until timePicker finish, to add the item to the list
   this.widget.litems.add(Reminder(
      time: time,
      date: date,
   ));
   setState((){});
}
```

If you don't want to use these, then you should add `showMaterialDatePicker` & `showMaterialTimePicker` to separate functions which returns a Future and handle the logic inside those functions.